# Load HTML& JS elements in another website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a snippet of javascript that my users can integrate in their website.The snippet would then load a series of elements such as divs, modals, toolstips.

A few years ago, I did this using an async javascript code that would load an iframe. Are there better ways to do this in 2019 than iframes?

Also, will my generic css iframe rules (i.e. a, div, common class names etc) interfer with the websites css? For example, can I use bootstrap or do I need to write custom css and be specific about targeting so I don't mess the other websites layout?

What else should I pay attention to?

Comment: I would try using AJAX to load directly into the page. Maybe include an div with an id in the snippet, so the AJAX has something specific to attach the code to.

Comment: I think you don't have permission on another website if load inside of iframe

Comment: I am thinking something along the lines of Google analytics or Facebook widgets (I.e. comments).